# unable to stop showing the empty data of the input in alert using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here  what I am doing is by using the Dynamic JSON I am generating the input fields
// JSON data

```
  data = [{ id: 'a', name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 'b', name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 'c', name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 'd', name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 'e', name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 'f', name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 'g', name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 'h', name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 'i', name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 'j', name: 'Tornado' }
  ]
```

By using the above data i am generating the inputs

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
    <input type="text" id={{x.id}} name={{x.name}} [ngModel]="sample" #ds>
</div>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="check()">Check</button>
<hr>
```

here my scenario is in an array I will mention some ids based on that if that input belongs to that id if it is empty then it should display border color red and display the field name in the alert

```
@ViewChildren('ds') inps: QueryList<ElementRef>;
   sample = 'Angular';
   text='';

/ only these ids containing fields should not be empty

  checkids = ['a','c','e'];

   check() {

    var arr=[];

    for (var x in this.inps) {

      if (x == "_results") {
       let idss;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.inps[x].length; i++) {
          idss = this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.getAttribute('id');
           if ((this.checkids.indexOf(idss) != -1) && !this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.value) {
             this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.style.borderColor = "red";
             var info =  this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.getAttribute('id');
           }
           arr.push(info)

        }
      }
    }

       if (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length) {
            this.text = "Please fill mandatory field's:" + arr;
             alert(this.text);

     } else {

     }



  }
```

**The problem I am facing is even the field is not empty which are mentioned in the checkids array it is showing like below**

[image]

**suppose if the given above checkids array is empty then  it repeating the field name like this**

[image]

how can solve this issue  if  give checkids are not empty then no alert has to be shown and if empty then only the fields name has to be shown

below is my stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-integration-sgsbpc

Answer (score 0):

You put
`arr.push(info)` just after closing bracket of if statement and it means that all fields will be added no matter if they are empty or required.

Beside that simple mistake you use property `_results` of `QueryList` which is private, instead use length to check whenever any items were found. I think the `var` isn't a way anymore, instead get into `const/let`. Using `!=` I would left for case when variable is `null` or `undefined`.

Edit 1:
Updated stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-integration-gs4r3c

Comment: could u make modification in stackblitz file